# List of fields to put on a REST call

Tags: 8

I have a rest resource configured from Rest UI page (let's say /entity/user: POST); I would like to share the endpoint with others devs so they can call the API (create users for e.g.). **Where to get the list of fields to put on request body? also their structure (value or target_id..)?**

Do you know a contrib module like this one that did the job for D7? https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_api_doc

Is there any programmatic practical way to have that? an API call or a drush command?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the module named OpenApi which provides a rest resource to describe the activated rest (and json) resources. It can be combined with two other modules OpenApi UI and ReDoc to have a nice user interface.

[image]

- https://www.drupal.org/project/openapi
- https://www.drupal.org/project/openapi_ui
- https://www.drupal.org/project/openapi_ui_redoc